# Internal and external fragmentation

Tags: filesystems, disk, fragmentation

Can anyone please tell me the difference between internal and external fragmentation while allocation of disk space for files?

Answer (score 185):

**External fragmentation**
Total memory space is enough to satisfy a request or to reside a process in it, but it is not contiguous so it can not be used.

[image: External fragmentation]

**Internal fragmentation**
Memory block assigned to process is bigger. Some portion of memory is left unused as it can not be used by another process.

[image: Internal fragmentation]

Answer (score 59):

First of all the term *fragmentation* cues there's an entity divided into parts — fragments.

- **Internal fragmentation:** Typical paper book is a collection of pages (text divided into pages). When a chapter's end isn't located at the end of page and new chapter starts from new page, there's a gap between those chapters and it's a waste of space — a chunk (page for a book) has unused space *inside* (*internally*) — "white space"
- **External fragmentation:** Say you have a paper diary and you didn't write your thoughts sequentially page after page, but, rather randomly. You might end up with a situation when you'd want to write 3 pages in row, but you can't since there're no 3 clean pages one-by-one, you might have 15 clean pages in the diary totally, but they're not contiguous

Comment: this is an amazing analogy to relate with.

Comment: Incredible analogy! Probably never going to forget this concept, thanks to this.

Comment: Just wow. For this analogy...

Answer (score 1):

I am an operating system that only allocates you memory in 10mb partitions.

**Internal Fragmentation**

- You ask for 17mb of memory
- I give you 20mb of memory

Fulfilling this request has just led to 3mb of internal fragmentation.

**External Fragmentation**

- You ask for 20mb of memory
- I give you 20mb of memory
- The 20mb of memory that I give you is **not** immediately contiguous next to another existing piece of allocated memory. In so handing you this memory, I have "split" a single unallocated space into two spaces.

Fulfilling this request has just led to external fragmentation

Answer (score -19):

Presumably from [this site](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/internal-external-memory-fragmentation-28851.html):

> Internal Fragmentation   Internal fragmentation occurs when the memory
>   allocator leaves extra space empty inside of a block of memory that
>   has been allocated for a client. This usually happens because the
>   processor’s design stipulates that memory must be cut into blocks of
>   certain sizes -- for example, blocks may be required to be evenly be
>   divided by four, eight or 16 bytes. When this occurs, a client that
>   needs 57 bytes of memory, for example, may be allocated a block that
>   contains 60 bytes, or even 64. The extra bytes that the client doesn’t
>   need go to waste, and over time these tiny chunks of unused memory can
>   build up and create large quantities of memory that can’t be put to
>   use by the allocator. Because all of these useless bytes are inside
>   larger memory blocks, the fragmentation is considered internal.
>
> External Fragmentation   External fragmentation happens when the
>   memory allocator leaves sections of unused memory blocks between
>   portions of allocated memory. For example, if several memory blocks
>   are allocated in a continuous line but one of the middle blocks in the
>   line is freed (perhaps because the process that was using that block
>   of memory stopped running), the free block is fragmented. The block is
>   still available for use by the allocator later if there’s a need for
>   memory that fits in that block, but the block is now unusable for
>   larger memory needs. It cannot be lumped back in with the total free
>   memory available to the system, as total memory must be contiguous for
>   it to be useable for larger tasks. In this way, entire sections of
>   free memory can end up isolated from the whole that are often too
>   small for significant use, which creates an overall reduction of free
>   memory that over time can lead to a lack of available memory for key
>   tasks.

Comment: Maddy, you seem to have copied this text from another site, probably [this one](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/internal-external-memory-fragmentation-28851.html). If you do that, at minimum, you're required to add a link back to the site, indicating where you copied it from. I've done that for you here. This is still a borderline answer, though - in the future, **please use information like this as the basis for an answer you write yourself, not as the entire answer**.